# Find objects having 3 maximum value for the `albumId` property in an array of objects e.g 100,99,98

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Here is json data
I want to retrieve those object who have maximum value 3 largest value may be 100,100,100 and 99,99

```
[
  
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/d32776",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 99,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 99,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/56a8c2",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/56a8c2"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 100,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/b0f7cc",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/b0f7cc"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 100,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/54176f",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/54176f"
  },
]
```

**what can be best solution maps,foreach,or reduce**

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. It will help us understand your problem better.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem.
What did you try? Can you show us your code?
Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When using map, you want to return a value for every iteration, but since you don't want an array with the same amount of values, this is not the best option.

this [codeburst article](https://codeburst.io/array-methods-explained-filter-vs-map-vs-reduce-vs-foreach-ea3127c6d319) might help

Of the three, reduce would probably be the best option but judging by the description you gave, I thing [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might be your solution here.

Comment: I just want latest 3 object (albumId is consider to be larger for latest)

Comment: Please provide me code if you can i tried many solution but failed

Comment: I don't fully understand as to what you are trying to implement, it would help if you post some of the code that you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wanted largest 3 (or num) objects which are based on `albumId`.

We can just sort desc based on albumId and get slice of array. Try this.

```js
const getLargest = (arr, num) =>
  arr
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => b.albumId - a.albumId)
    .slice(0, num);

const data = [
  {
    albumId: 1,
    id: 4,
    title: "culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/d32776",
    thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776",
  },
  {
    albumId: 99,
    id: 5,
    title: "natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97",
    thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97",
  },
  {
    albumId: 99,
    id: 6,
    title: "accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/56a8c2",
    thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/56a8c2",
  },
  {
    albumId: 100,
    id: 7,
    title: "officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/b0f7cc",
    thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/b0f7cc",
  },
  {
    albumId: 100,
    id: 8,
    title: "aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/54176f",
    thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/54176f",
  },
];

console.log(getLargest(data, 3));
```